# Is having the same part number enough for the LCD cable to be compatible?

Tags: laptop, cable, lcd

Laptop I've got is Acer 5551-a.

I need to replace the LCD cable, it appears to be broken in one place, screen displays distortions but stops displaying them if one bent part of the cable is moved. I want to get a new one instead of fixing the one I have.

LCD cable part number is DC020010L10 (written on the cable itself) . It also says Rev 2.0 after the name.

[part #1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ASPIRE-5742Z-SCREEN-RIBBON-DC020010L10/dp/B00NV16VY4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1463067571&sr=8-1&keywords=DC020010L10) This one does not mention my laptop model or the revision number, and has "C7" added after the part number.

```
ACER ASPIRE 5742 5742Z 15.6" LED SCREEN VIDEO FLEX CABLE RIBBON DC020010L10 C7
```

[part #2](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Display-Cable-Acer-50-R4F02-009-DC020010L10/dp/B0171UXJXG/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1463067571&sr=8-3&keywords=DC020010L10) This one does not mention my laptop model or the revision number.

```
Display Cable Acer - 50.R4F02.009 Compatible with Aspire 5250 | 5252 |
5253 | 5253G | 5333 | 5336 | 5342 | 5552 | 5552G |
5733 | 5733Z | 5736Z | 5741G | 5742 | 5742G | 5742Z | 5742ZG E Series
E442 | E443 | E529 | E642 | E642G | E644 | E644G | E729 | E729Z EasyNote
TK11 | TK11BZ | TK13 | TK13BZ | TK36 | TK37 | TK81 | TK83 | TK85 | TK87
and part # DC020010L10
```

Would any of these cables work with my laptop? They have the same part number, but different revision number. And these cables don't list my laptop model under compatible ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Contact the seller of the park and ask.  The provided information isn't reliable enough to answer this question.

Comment: If the connectors look right, I'd go for "part #1": it's only a fiver, after all.